# Cellular missing from Network & Internet in Windows 10 after Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709, cellular

After Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, I can’t connect to a cellular network.

My setup is onfiguration:

- **PC**: Lenovo T450s,
- **OS**: Windows 10 Pro v 1709 (16299.125)
- **Modem**: Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE

Before update, everythings was OK, but after restart with update I don't have cellular network in tray icon Network, and even in Settings -> Network and Internet.

But in the network connections there is configured cellular network and it’s **turned on**. When I click on connect/disconnect with default I should be landed on Settings -> Network & Internet -> Cellular. But I landed in Settings -> Network & Internet -> WiFi.

How can I force turn on cellular settings? Register? Netsh?
Of course I tried to remove the modem from device manager, reinstall drivers, etc… And nothing has worked.